# Weird behavior when overloading using variable arguments with primitive types in java

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions, autoboxing

Clearly I've not enough knowledge of how overloading, autoboxing and variable arguments work.

So here's the program causing trouble whenever there's an involvement of primitive types.

```
public static void z(int a, Object...objects){
}
public static void z(Object...objects){
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    z();    // no error
    z(4);   // Compile time Error : Ambiguous

    z2();               // No error
    z2(true, "sadas");  // Error

    // No problem with reference types
    z3();       // No error. String one called
    z3(5);      // No error. Object one called

    z4();       // Error
    z4(4);      // Error
    z4("asdas");    // Working properly
}
public static void z2(boolean b, Object...objects){
}
public static void z2(Object...objects){
}
public static void z3(String...objects){
    System.out.println("String one called");
}
public static void z3(Object...objects){
    System.out.println("Object one called");
}
public static void z4(int...objects){
    System.out.println("int z4 called");
}
public static void z4(Object...objects){
    System.out.println("Object z4 called");
}
```

**Can anybody explain why any of this is happening?** I can happily use **Integer, Boolean** instead of int, boolean but would very much like to know internal working behind it.

Comment: You've got 9 calls in there. Explaining the overloading for every single one of them would be a very long job - which ones are you actually confused about, precisely?

Comment: @JonSkeet last three for z4() would give me overall idea, I think

Comment: Relevant SO-Documentation: [Autoboxing](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/138/autoboxing#t=201703141226134363766)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method call will not compile if the compiler cannot determine which of the overloaded method variants it should use.

Let's use `z4` as an example:

1. The method call `z4()` fits the signature of both variants.
2. The method call `z4(4)` also fits the signature of both variants because the variable can be auto-boxed.
3. The method call `z4("asdas")` is not ambiguous, as `String` cannot be cast to `int`.

*Update*: the rules for resolving overloaded method calls are as follows:

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
>
> ...
>
> The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase.
>
> ...
>
> The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

If more than one variant is selected in the same phase, then the most specific one is chosen,* but in short `z3(String...)` is more specific than `z3(Object...)`, while `z4(int...)` and `z4(Object...)` are equally specific.

*The rules for determining this most specific variant are somewhat complicated (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5))

Comment: By that logic, z3() should also be ambiguous

Comment: That is my understanding as well, however, changing `public static void z(int a, Object...objects){}` to `public static void z(Integer a, Object...objects){}` lets `z(4);` compile. Why?

Comment: @bruceleefinalkungfu nope, both signatures match. Java could use either one. I do not know why it uses the `String` variant. I tried changing their order, it did not matter.

Comment: @bruceleefinalkungfu I've updated to the answer to address your comment.

Comment: To extend on that a little bit: (String...) is more specific than (Object...) exactly because String is more specific than Object (as Object is a super class of String). Using two unrelated types, e.g. String and Integer results in an ambiguity error once again

Answer (score 0):

Thats a fab question

Now consider

```
public static void z2(boolean b, Object... objects) {
    }

    public static void z2(Object... objects) {
    }
```

Both methods have a vararg argument, which means they will both be considered on the third and final phase of overloading resolution.

Remember Object class is the mother of all objects in java

Well this explains one thing

The compiler can treat both as object which will result in object array again.

Now finally

```
void z2(boolean b, Object... objects)
    public static void z2(Object... objects)
```

is treated as same function.

To check you can comment

```
    z2(true); 
    z2(true, "sadas");
```

removing either of

```
public static void z2(boolean b, Object... objects) {
            }
Or
    public static void z2(Object... objects) {
    }
```

This will work.
But

You have taken object inside parameter

If you are specific for example

```
   public static void z2(boolean b, String... objects) {

        }
        public static void z2(String... objects) {
        }
z2(); // No error
z2(true, "sadas"); // No error
```

This way it can be resolved

Comment: z3(5) is resolved cuz no z3(String...s ) can't be called. z4(5) is ambiguous cuz both z4(Object...a) , z4(int...a) can be called whereas it would not have been the case in z3("jdksaj"); Somehow using primitive can confuse the compiler

Comment: Yes exactly true, but we can use z4(Integer... objects) ; insted of z4(int... objects) which solves that